# Upgraded to VS2017 from VS2013 how do I edit while debugging aspx.cs files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I just upgraded to VS2017 from VS2013 (finally!). A big change I'm noticing is that in VS2013 when attached to `w3wp.exe` for debugging ASPX pages I was able to edit the `aspx.cs` files while attached and running and then just reload the page.

Now it appears I cannot do this in VS2017; I have to stop debugging, make changes and start debugging again which is pretty slow.  Is there a way to enable edit during debugging in VS2017?

Comment: Did you try the following method?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx

Comment: Yes, I did find that link via Google searching and that setting was already enabled.